# Python Exception in finally clause eats prior exceptions

Tags: python, exception, finally, try-finally, try-except

In my real case a `Segmentation fault` arises in the `finally` clause which I can't do anything about because it stems from an external library used via ctypes. Actually, I don't care about this segfault because the script is done anyway.

However, the segfault in the finally eats all Exceptions occuring prior to it. Thus, debugging that first `NameError` from `iDontExist` becomes a pain in the ass. It doesn't occur anywhere. Currently there is no way of seeing any raised Exceptions from before the segfault.

```
def f1():
    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print iDontExist

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        f1()
    finally:
        raise Exception("segfault here")
        print "finally"
```

What do you think I could do about it? Fixing the external library is not an option.

Comment: A segfault isn't an `Exception`; it's a signal that causes the OS to kill your program, not something you can catch in an `except` block. If you just want to make sure anything buffered before the segfault is written, you could try `sys.stdout.flush(); sys.stderr.flush()` before the line that might segfault. If you want to catch and log the exception before the segfault, put an `except` block before the `finally` to log it. If you want something else… what do you want?

Comment: If I put `sys.stdout.flush(); sys.stderr.flush()` before the `raise Exception("segfault here")` it still doesn't show the `NameError`.

What I want: see any Exceptions being raised before anything that happens in the `finally` clause

Comment: Well, yes, that's because the `NameError` hasn't been printed yet. It gets printed as part of the normal exit-interpreter-via-uncaught-exception. If you don't exit that way, you need to get it printed in some other way. (As in EOL's sample.)

Comment: Instead of manually flushing stdout/stderr, try `python -u` for unbuffered binary stdout,stderr. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to catch exceptions before your finally:

```
try:
    f1()
except NameError as error:  # Change as needed
    print "Error caught:", error  # Or simply "raise", in order to raise the error caught
finally:
    raise Exception("segfault here")
    print "finally"
```

That said, abamert is right: a segmentation fault is not an exception, so you might be looking for something else.

Comment: It would be better to show, e.g., `except Exception as e:` and then code that prints out something based on `e`, instead of just the comments.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm still not 100% clear on what the OP wants, but if he just wants to see something about the `NameError` before a segfault in the `finally` kills his interpreter, this is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: @abamert: I put an explicit example.

Comment: Yeah this is probably the best way to do it. It's still missing line numbers etc. Better than nothing, though.

Comment: @user1085954: Instead of just printing `error`, you can print the whole traceback. See the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module, the [`exc_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) function, etc. for details. I think EOL was just giving you a sample of what you can do, not trying to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: @user1085954: I added in the code, as a comment, that you can also do `raise` and recover the full, usual Python error output.

Comment: @EOL: False. It doesn't raise the `NameError` with `raise`. This shows the full range of my original problem: every Exception prior to an Exception (or program crash) in the finally clause is being eaten.

Comment: @user1085954: I am not sure I understand what you mean (because replacing `f1()` by `raise NameError("error")` does make `raise` re-raise the `NameError` exception). In any case, if you need to catch an exception in the `finally` clause, you need to use another `try… except` structure *there* (i.e. inside the `finally` clause).